# how to get group by dataframe on the basis of year or week and how to combine two dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
Dataset 1 : Sales Representative ID, Customer ID, Order Date, Revenue
Dataset 2 : Manager ID, Sales Representative ID, Create Date, Termination date
```

Given Above 2 datasets where “Dataset 1” represents daily revenue data related to a customer and
the sales representative associated with that customer AND “Dataset 2” has mapping of sales
representative with the manager id associated with it in that particular point in time where “Create
Date” represents when new association is created and “Termination date” represents when
association is terminated.

i have to calculate year,month,week and day wise revenue for each manager id for
every date.

```
Output Dataset: Order Date, Year/Month/Week/Day,Manager ID, Total Revenue
```

I am confused with two things here how to combine these two dataset and secondly how to get the revenue week,year and day wise like i dont know any way in pandas to group by them according to above. Please help

```
dataset1 = { 'srid':[1,2,3,1,5],
            'custid':[11,12,43,12,34],
            'orderdate':["1/2/2019","1/2/2019","2/2/2019","1/2/2019","1/2/2019"],
            'Rev':[100,101,102,103,17]
}


dataset2 = {
    'manid':[101,102,103,104,105],
    'srid':[1,2,1,3,5],
    'CreateDate':["1/1/2019","1/1/2019","3/1/2019","1/1/2019","1/1/2019"],
    'TerminationDate':["2/1/2019","3/1/2019","5/1/2019","2/1/2019","2/1/2019"]
}
```

Comment: Please post a sample of Dataset 1 and 2. It's not easy to help without that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dataset1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dataset2)

df = df1.merge(df2, on=['srid'])
df['orderdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['orderdate'])
df['CreateDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CreateDate'])
df['TerminationDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TerminationDate'])

# Daily
df_d = df.groupby(by=['manid', pd.Grouper(key='orderdate', freq='D')]).agg({'Rev': 'sum'})
# Monthly
df_m = df.groupby(by=['manid', pd.Grouper(key='orderdate', freq='M')]).agg({'Rev': 'sum'})
# Weekly
df_w = df.groupby(by=['manid', pd.Grouper(key='orderdate', freq='W')]).agg({'Rev': 'sum'})
# Yearly
df_y = df.groupby(by=['manid', pd.Grouper(key='orderdate', freq='Y')]).agg({'Rev': 'sum'})
print(df_y)

                  Rev
manid orderdate
101   2019-12-31  203
102   2019-12-31  101
103   2019-12-31  203
104   2019-12-31  102
105   2019-12-31   17
```

Comment: can you tell me some good resource to study group by all arguments and how to add agggregate functions to it?

Answer (score 0):

great answer above, you can also easily use df.resample(rule='MS').sum() for different time intervals( M: month, MS: start of month, D: day and so on)